# Sign of Cohen's d is unaffected by reversing order of factor levels in R

Tags: r

I'm using Cohen's d (implemented using `cohen.d()` from the `effsize` package) as a measure of effect size in my dependent variable between two levels of a factor.

My code looks like this: `cohen.d(d, f)` where `d` is a vector of numeric values and `f` is a factor with two levels: "A" and "B".

Based on my understanding, the sign of Cohen's d is dependent on the order of means (i.e. factor levels) entered into the formula. However, my `cohen.d()` command returns a negative value (and negative CIs), even if I reverse the order of levels in `f`.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library('effsize')
# Load in Chickweight data
a=ChickWeight

# Cohens d requires two levels in factor f, so take the first two available in Diet
a=a[a$Diet==c(1,2),]
a$Diet=a$Diet[ , drop=T]

# Compute cohen's d with default order of Diet
d1 = a$weight
f1 = a$Diet
cohen1 = cohen.d(d1,f1)

# Re-order levels of Diet
a$Diet = relevel(a$Diet, ref=2)

# Re-compute cohen's d
d2 = a$weight
f2 = a$Diet
cohen2 = cohen.d(d2,f2)

# Compare values
cohen1
cohen2
```

Can anyone explain why this is the case, and/or if I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the reasoning behind the issue in your example is (maybe someone else can comment here), but if you look at the examples under `?cohen.d`, there are a few different methods for calculating it:

```
treatment = rnorm(100,mean=10)
control = rnorm(100,mean=12)
d = (c(treatment,control))
f = rep(c("Treatment","Control"),each=100)
## compute Cohen's d
## treatment and control
cohen.d(treatment,control)
## data and factor
cohen.d(d,f)
## formula interface
cohen.d(d ~ f)
```

If you use the first example of `cohen.d(treatment, control)` and reverse that to `cohen.d(control, treatment)` you get the following:

```
cohen.d(treatment, control)
Cohen's d

d estimate: -1.871982 (large)
95 percent confidence interval:
      inf       sup 
-2.206416 -1.537547 

cohen.d(control, treatment)
Cohen's d

d estimate: 1.871982 (large)
95 percent confidence interval:
     inf      sup 
1.537547 2.206416
```

So using the two-vector method from the examples with your data, we can do:

```
a1 <- a[a$Diet == 1,"weight"]
a2 <- a[a$Diet == 2,"weight"]
cohen3a <- cohen.d(a1, a2)
cohen3b <- cohen.d(a2, a1)
```

I noticed that `f` in the `?cohen.d` examples is not a factor, but a character vector. I tried playing around with the `cohen.d(d, f)` method, but didn't find a solution. Would like to see if someone else has anything regarding that.